# SQLAlchemy relationship problems - mapper fails to locate name

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables where I'm trying to set up a one-to-many relationship. There should be a single `Player` with multiple `Sessions`.

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Session(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'session'

    id = sql.Column('session_id', sql.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    player_id = sql.Column(sql.INTEGER, sql.ForeignKey('player.player_id'))

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'

    id = sql.Column('player_id', sql.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    sessions = relationship('Session', backref='player')
```

However, the error I keep getting when creating the database is

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - 
can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 
'Mapper|Player|player'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper 
Mapper|Player|player, expression 'Session' failed to locate a name ("name 
'Session' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this 
relationship() to the <class 'analysis_db_tables.Player'> class after both 
dependent classes have been defined.
```

I've tried switching the order of `Player` and `Session`, removing the `relationship` line down outside of `Player` as

```
Player.sessions = relationship('Session', backref='player')
```

and I've also tried using `back_populates` with `relationship` statements in both classes. What am I doing wrong here?

This issue popped up seemingly randomly while building my database code, and I've paired down the tables to just these two while still recreating the problem. I'm using SQLAlchemy with postgres. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sessions = sql.relationship('Session', backref='player')
```

Instead of:

```
sessions = relationship('Session', backref='player')
```

Comment: Making that change just throws the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedColumnError: Could not initialize target column for ForeignKey 'player.id' on table 'session': table 'player' has no column named 'id'`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you included the name "product_id" on your column. I've modified my answer to another possible issue.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that either. I'm getting relationship directly from `from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship`